# How to use Automapper in .net core class library?

Tags: c#, automapper, cqrs, asp.net-core-2.2, mediatr

I am developing microservices using asp.net core 2.2 and following CQRS pattern. I am using Mediatr package and following the command and query pattern. I have multiple handlers in the command layer(.netcore class library). In this class library I am trying to map the incoming data from request to the entity class object which has many properties.

```
public class CreateUserCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateSystemUserCommand, CreateSystemUserCommandResponse>
{
    private readonly IIntegrationEventPublisherServiceService _eventcontext;
    private readonly SystemUserRepository _systemUserRepository;
    public CreateUserCommandHandler(IIntegrationEventPublisherServiceService eventcontext)
    {
        _systemUserRepository = new SystemUserRepository(new TaxatHand_StgContext());
        _eventcontext = eventcontext;
    }

    public async Task<CreateSystemUserCommandResponse> Handle(CreateSystemUserCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var user = new SystemUsers{FirstName = request.FirstName, Email = request.Email, LastName = request.LastName, Level = request.Level, Location = request.Location, MobilePhoneNumber = request.MobilePhoneNumber, Role = Convert.ToInt32(request.Role), WorkPhoneNumber = request.WorkPhoneNumber};
    }
}
```

I thought of using Automapper and then added the nuget pacakge: AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.

Now how to manage the DI part in this implementation. In every example I see the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // Automapper
   services.AddAutoMapper();
}
```

But in this implementation there is no Startup.cs page where I can setup the above code.

Can anyone help me in this by providing their guidence with some sample examples.

Comment: Is this class library intended to be used just by the apps in this solution? Or will it be published as a NuGet package?

Comment: This class library is intended to be used by the apps in this solution only.

Comment: In that case, why not put `services.AddAutoMapper();` in the Startup.cs of the consuming application?

Comment: Thanks a lot Mason for your inputs. It helped me a lot :)